# Use box shadow inside scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I've a problem. I'm implementing a wrapper with 3 divs inside. Each div has a min width. When I shrink the browser and the min width get's reached, the overflow: auto get's enabled. The problem is now that my boy shadow get's cut off in this case. Maybe there is a way to handle this that the shadow is still there?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

span {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>HI</span>
    <span>HI</span>
    <span>HI</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a padding to your container ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser I could but this would destroy the design :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add padding to the root of box.

simply add "padding: 5px;" to the "div" like this.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

span {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

}

span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>HI</span>
    <span>HI</span>
    <span>HI</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i put your code in code pen and i put margin in span selector and your box shadow won't go away

```
div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

span {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

if i'm wrong tell me maybe i can help you then

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
      span {
        min-width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
/*        box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);*/
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset;
      }
```